# Low Quality Review - Why is this answer offensive or repulsive?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to get up to speed on Low Quality Review, and I don't understand why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11916653) is offensive or repulsive.  While it's not a great answer, it's still an answer.  Was the offensive part removed?  If so, how was I supposed to know it contained something offensive at one point?

[image: offensive answer]

NOTE:  the linked website is a site about scooters.

---

I don't believe this is a duplicate of the question regarding spam because I'm asking why it's offensive or repulsive.  If the answer was flagged as spam, I wouldn't have asked the question because it's not a far stretch to understand why it would be spam.

Comment: That's spam I believe :-)

Comment: I can see not being repulsed by spam if you're used to it, but...

Comment: @gnat - My question is why it's offensive, not why it's spam.

Comment: I for one am offended by spam in questions / answers here. Re-check the explanation of audit failure: "it is ...spam... - readers will find it offensive..."

Comment: @devlincarnate You may be missing the point a bit. See my edit to my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not offensive; it's spam. It's also very low quality (VLQ), as it is nothing more than a link. You said it looks OK. It doesn't. That's about all there is to say there.

---

Based on the comments, you may be missing the point. The failed audit message doesn't say the answer was offensive. It says, in part,

> It is abusive nonsense, noise, **spam**, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable - *readers will find it offensive or repulsive* instead of helpful.

(Emphasis added.) The point isn't that the post was rude or obscene. It's that it's spam, which is not helpful.

Comment: Ok.  So spam is an answer that recommends a plugin and it should be deleted?  Is spam considered "offensive" ?

Comment: No, spam is anything that "Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation." The post in question does nothing other than promote a product, which just happens to be a plugin in that case. I think most of us would say spam is offensive, the way we use "offensive" in everyday speech. But for purposes of flagging that answer, use the "spam" flag, not the "offensive" flag.

Comment: Ok, I got it now.  Thanks.

Comment: And what about the hundreds of thousands of 2 to 5 worded answers that are highly scored?

Comment: @BillBEGUERADJ What about them? Also, pretty sure there are not "hundreds of thousands" of them, especially since the system rejects anything under 30 characters.

Comment: I mean they still exist (and referred to). The deleted answer the OP took a screenshot of is worthier than many existing answers (even highly reputed members do not hesitate to post comment like answers)

Comment: @BillBEGUERADJ So, they exist. If they're valid answers (that is, they actually answer the question, or at least try to), so what? Sometimes, the answer really is very short. And no, that deleted answer is *not* worthier than many other existing answers. It is spam and therefore garbage. If you see answers that are worse than that, you should be flagging them. But please don't take this as an indication that you should go hunting for ancient, low-quality answers. If you *see* them, flag them; don't go looking for problems that aren't bothering anybody.