# Why didn't I pass this low quality post review test?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I have looked at several related questions, and I think this situation is different to all of them. Some existing questions about this have a lot of down votes, which almost put me off asking, but I think it's important that I understand this. Here are some of the potential 'duplicates':

- [Asker misunderstood that spam should be deleted in the low quality queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320541/low-quality-review-why-is-this-answer-offensive-or-repulsive)
- [Asker did not realise that question was already answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284856/failed-review-audit-because-answer-looked-good-to-me-but-it-had-been-deleted-as)
- [Asker did not realise poster had made many similar answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262175/unclear-spam-review-audit)

The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720134/net-analogues-of-spring-batch). Note that what I was shown in the review queue, and has already deleted, was in my opinion a better answer than what's visible as the answer from the same user now, as it provided direct links to the framework being suggested. The *additional* text from the review queue, compared to the more recent answer is:

> To download SummerBatch go to: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SummerBatch/ For additional documentation on SummerBatch visit: https://www.bluage.com/docs/summerbatch/refguide/mp_referenceguide.xhtml Website: SummerBatch.com

My thoughts on this answer were:

- It's not my field, but the answer seems to provide exactly what's being asked for; it's not off-topic
- It is the only answer to this question
- The user doesn't seem to have posted anything else about this framework in other questions, and the framework is open source anyway; this doesn't strike me as being spam
- The links check out, as in, they are real pages relevant to the answer

All I'm left with is that perhaps the answerer has some undisclosed affiliation with the framework; this being the case, how would I work this out? In any case, I would not see answering a question with a link to my own open source framework as "offensive or repulsive", unless it was clearly spam that I was posting in many questions.

**Edit**: In addition to my list above, the answer is also similar in content to a comment by the same user, that the asker clearly found helpful.

**Edit 2**: The whole question has now been deleted as off topic, see [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10720134/timeline).

Comment: The answer actually was closed as spam.

Comment: @Tunaki How can it be a duplicate to ask why this particular post is spam? Yes the topic is the same but I don't see the link

Comment: @scary_jeff that user was originally spamming their product and that answer was flagged as spam accordingly. Also - take out the links - then re-read the post - it's nothing more than "Here's how to download xyz..." - I've removed the question entirely now - it was off-topic, had few views and was just attracting rubbish as answers.

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the feedback. Yes the answer is not much more than a link to a framework, but this was exactly what the question was asking for. I looked for other answers by this user from their profile, and did not find any other answers referencing this framework; how would I find the posts you are referring to? It seems like the actual issue here is that the *question* was bad.

Comment: @scary_jeff indeed - bad questions that are off-topic (especially resource requests) - tend to lead to answers that are just links. The fact that the question remained open long enough to get answers doesn't invalidate the fact that "here's how to download XYZ" isn't an answer though...